# C# Spring context dictionary expression as a key

Tags: c#, spring, expression, config

Is there a way to use expression as a key in the Dictionary?
The value of this expression would be a value from the other dictionary.

Im looking for something like

```
<object id="meta-naming-configurator" singleton="true"
              type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string, string&gt;, mscorlib">
        <constructor-arg>
          <dictionary key-type="string" value-type="string">
            <entry key="assets" value="other_asset"/>
          </dictionary>
        </constructor-arg>
      </object>

<object id="table-matrics-key" 
              singleton="true"
              type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string, ListString&gt;, mscorlib"
              depends-on="meta-naming-configurator">
        <constructor-arg>
          <dictionary key-type="string" value-type="ListString">
            <entry key="@(meta-naming-configurator)['assets']" value-ref="assets-tables-list"/>
          </dictionary>
        </constructor-arg>
      </object>
```

..but working.

Thanks

Comment: You can use any object as key for your map as long as it implements `Equals`-and `GetHashCode`-methods

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure you have understood my question. If so, can you, please, correct my config example?

Comment: I'm talking here about using EXPRESSION which have to be evaluated as a key. see the example code I have provided.